# solving equation with standard normal variables

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose that $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Now I want to find k such that $P(Z>k)+P(5Z>k)=0.05$. I want to find this $k$ numerically, but I'm stuck in which way this can be done.
Hopefully anyone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Zeroth iteration: find $k_0$ s.t. $P(5Z>k_0)=0.05$. Second iteration: find $P(5Z>k_1)=0.05-P(Z>k_0)$. Continue. Just two iteration will give you a great approximation.

Answer (score 0):

The Comment by @A.S. seems sensible. The use of Chebyshev's
inequality to get a precise result seems inappropriate. 
Meanwhile, this question just sits without a recognized response. Here is another approach  to get a numerical solution.

If you rewrite
the question as finding $k$ such that 
$$[1 - P(Z \leq k)] + [1 - P(Z \leq k/5)] = .05,$$
then the following 'grid search' in R looks at many
values of $k$ between 0 and 10, to see which one
comes closest. (The code `pnorm` is the CDF of standard
normal in R.)

```
 k = seq(0,10,by=.001)  # grid
 q = 1 - pnorm(k) + 1 - pnorm(k/5)
 error = abs(q - .05)
 k[error == min(error)]
 ## 8.224
```

You can check the result using normal tables or software.
It is correct to three places.